# Error message Could not cast value type error - Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, edit

Recently I added the below code in order to get some user entered data to appear when the edit button was tapped. But instead of opening the edit view controller, the app freezes.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{

    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")

        let MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as! EditfreshreleaseViewController
        vc.selectedFreshRelease = self.freshreleases[indexPath.row]
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        success(true)



    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue



    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
    }
```

When I tap the edit button, the app crashes with the below error message:

Update action ...
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1d37e81e0) to 'fresh_release.EditfreshreleaseViewController' (0x1043d7248).
2018-12-17 20:56:30.547305-0500 fresh release[7644:1985252] Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1d37e81e0) to 'fresh_release.EditfreshreleaseViewController' (0x1043d7248).
(lldb)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your `EditfreshreleaseViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. That is why your cast didn't work.

You need to first cast the VC to `UINavigationController`, then cast the `topViewController` to `EditfreshreleaseViewController`.

Change the line:

```
let vc = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as! EditfreshreleaseViewController
```

to

```
let navVC = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as! UINavigationController
let vc = navVC.topViewController as! EditfreshreleaseViewController
```

Comment: now got the error message: thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @sckring Can you show your storyboard? Specifically, show the controller with the ID "FreshReleaseEdit" and the controller that is connected to it.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to post a picture on here. Do I need 10 reputation points in order to do that?

Comment: @sckring Just upload it to imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: @sckring Your navigation controller is not connected to anything. I assume you want to show the controller on the right? You should control+drag from the navigation controller to the controller on the right, then select "root view controller".